# display table header on each page print

Tags: html, css, print-css

I have my table header contents which I want to print on each page on over flowing table body data. I tried thead display: table-header-group but it doesn't seem to help.Any suggestions on how to make it work in IE10 or chrome?.

HTML.

```
<table>
  <thead>
       <div>
          My print content
       </div>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
        <tr> Test <tr>
        <tr> Test <tr>
        ...
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: For `<thead>` permitted content: zero or more `<tr>` elements.

Comment: I did print the div content on the first page, However I want to repeat the header content on subsequent print pages.

Comment: What you have is invalid HTML at the moment, it may work if you get that corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<tr><td>My print content</td></tr>` instead. thead only takes tr inside it and tr only takes td inside it

Comment: The issue here is with div or tr I am able to print the table header of first page print. However on subsequent pages print I am not able to repeat the header.